# How do you get a Knockback 100 bow in 1.8.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant figure out how to get a knockback 100 bow in 1.8.9

Comment: We need a "too specialized" flag. I mean, we have a "too broad" one.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How do you make a bow knockback 100 i want to do it because i want to go really far like that 1 video

Answer (score 2):

`/enchant` does not allow for enchantments above their normal maximum level to be applied, so you will need to use a command that lets you specify NBTData, such as `/give`:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow 1 0 {ench:[{id:19,lvl:100}]}
```

`id:19` is the ID for the knockback enchantment, and `lvl:100` makes the enchantment level 100 as you wanted it. Together, they are a compound tag in the `ench:[]` list of the bow.

Comment: The command you gave me isn't doing any Knockback :(

Comment: @RandyNguyen You will need to use the punch enchantment, id 49. Knockback increases melee knockback, punch increases bow knockback.

Answer (score -3):

You normally can't. Press your chat key while holding a bow and type in:

```
/enchant @p knockback 100
```

or something like that.
It's considered cheating though, and can only be done in a cheats-enabled world.

Comment: This doesn't actually work